# GitHub Actions only /tmp/unit-tests-2f311f40.sh: 1: jest: not found

Tags: jestjs, github-actions

I have a pipeline in GitHub Actions and it is suggesting that it cannot find Jest despite it working locally.

If I run `npm run unit-tests` locally it works fine, but in the CI I get the following error:

```
> jest --group=unit --coverage --verbose

/tmp/unit-tests-2f311f40.sh: 1: jest: not found
```

```yaml
name: staging-pipeline

on:
  push:
    tags:
    - 'v*-staging'

env:
  CI: true
  NODE_ENV: production

jobs:
  unit-test:
    name: unit-test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@master
    - name: Unit Tests 
      run: |
        npm install
        npm run unit-tests
```

```json
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "app",
  "main": "",
  "scripts": {
    "ts-node": "ts-node",
    "test": "jest",
    "unit-tests": "jest --group=unit --coverage --verbose",
    "prisma-generate": "npx prisma generate && npm install @prisma/client"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@prisma/client": "^4.3.1",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "axios-retry": "^3.3.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.2",
    "mongodb": "^4.9.1",
    "qs": "^6.11.0",
    "winston": "^3.8.1",
    "zod": "^3.18.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/aws-lambda": "^8.10.102",
    "@types/jest": "^29.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^18.7.15",
    "@types/qs": "^6.9.7",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.36.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.36.1",
    "esbuild": "^0.15.7",
    "eslint": "^8.23.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "jest": "^28.1.3",
    "jest-mock-extended": "^2.0.7",
    "jest-runner-groups": "^2.2.0",
    "json-schema-to-ts": "^2.5.5",
    "prettier": "2.7.1",
    "prisma": "^4.3.1",
    "ts-jest": "^28.0.8",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^4.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.8.2"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see in my CI i have the following variable

```
  NODE_ENV: production
```

This was causing npm to only install the dependencies and not the devDependencies. equivalant of doing `npm install --prod` once i removed this env variable, it was able to install jest and use it as normal.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you installed jest globally on your local machine so `Jest` command is available in your local machine but not the case in Github action environment(container), so you have to way to fix it :

1.install jest globally in in Github action environment.

```
  jobs:
  unit-test:
    name: unit-test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@master
    - name: Unit Tests 
      run: |
        npm install
        npm install -g jest
        npm run unit-tests
```

2.or in your package.json file change the `npm run unit-test` to
`./node_modules/.bin/jest --group=unit --coverage --verbos` to read
I recommend the second way.

Comment: But they have Jest in their dev dependencies, which means the executable will be symlinked into `./node_modules/.bin/`, which is added to the path when `npm run` is used (so why you'd recommend the second way I've no idea, it's redundant).

Comment: yes you are correct, I didn't pay attention that jest is a dev dependency